# Python Summation Higher Order Function

Tags: python

I'm writing an iterative solution for summation, and it seems to give the correct answer. But I'm told by my tutor that it's giving the wrong result for `non-commutative combine operations`. I went to google but I'm still unsure what exactly it means...

Here is the recursive code I wrote:

```
def sum(term, a, next, b):
    # First recursive version
    if a > b:
        return 0
    else:
        return term(a) + sum(term, next(a), next, b)

def accumulate(combiner, base, term, a, next, b):
    # Improved version
    if a > b:
        return base
    else:
        return combiner(term(a), accumulate(combiner, base, term, next(a), next, b))

print(sum(lambda x: x, 1, lambda x: x, 5))
print(accumulate(lambda x,y: x+y, 0, lambda x: x, 1, lambda x: x, 5))
# Both solution equate to - 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
```

This is the iterative version I wrote that gives the wrong results for `non-commutative combine operations` - 
Edit: accumulate_iter gives the wrong results when `lambda x,y: x- y` is used for combiner

```
def accumulate_iter(combiner, null_value, term, a, next, b):
    while a <= b:
        null_value = combiner(term(a), null_value)
        a = next(a)
    return null_value
```

Hoping if someone could provide a solution for this iterative version of `accumulate`

Comment: Non-commutative just means that it's not guaranteed that `a + b == b + a`. You have to make sure that you are passing the operands to `+` in the order they appear in the sequence.

Comment: Please clarify: a) `accumulate` is [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), b) if so: why are you trying to create own version of `sum` through already implemented `accumulate` - what is the purpose of such exercize?

Comment: For example, list concatenation is not commutative. `[2] + [3] == [2,3] != [3,2] == [3] + [2]`.

Comment: opps, sorry I put in the wrong function, just changed it

Comment: oh @AlexYu the website is for a different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `accumulate_iter` works fine when the combiner is commutative, but it gives different result when the combiner is non-commutative. That's because the recursive `accumulate` combine elements from the back to the front, but the iterative version combine them from the front to the back.

So what we need to do is to make `accumulate_iter` combine from behind, and following is a rewritten `accumulate_iter`:

```
def accumulate_iter(a, b, base, combiner, next, term):
    # we want to combine from behind, 
    # but it's hard to do that since we are iterate from ahead
    # here we first go through the process, 
    # and store the elements encounted into a list
    l = []
    while a <= b:
        l.append(term(a))
        a = next(a)
    l.append(base)
    print(l)

    # now we can combine from behind!
    while len(l)>1:
        l[-2] = combiner(l[-2], l[-1])
        l.pop()
    return l[0]
```

Comment: oh thank you! I realised that after thinking for awhile, but wasn't sure how I can edit the code to do so from back to front